# System.DateTime.Now is giving bad results

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

The main logic of a utility tool is in a function like this:

```
private void Run()
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    Prepare();
    Search();
    Process();
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
    Console.WriteLine("Run took {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
        (int)duration.TotalHours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);
}
```

When I run this I can see with my own eyes it is taking at least 5 seconds (`Process()` method spews console output which I can observe happening for 5-6s). But it reports "Run took 00:00:01".

I don't expect time to have microsecond precision but why is it so totally inaccurate here?

**Update:**
Following advice I also ran a `StopWatch` over the same period and compared against subtracting two `DateTime`, and also debugged the code. The two methods agree to a fraction of a second... `StopWatch` in the debugger had 1139 milliseconds. My hypothesis is that somehow time writing to the console is not included but I have no way to back that up (or disprove it).

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: i guess you should use a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and also have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754018/recommended-method-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timespans/8754105#8754105)

Comment: Are you aware of the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class?

Comment: is the value in the duration TimeSpan around 5-6 sec, and its an issue of incorrect displaying???

Comment: i run you code and i didnt find any problem  in this,. try to debug code

Comment: See also - http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that the problem is with `DateTime`. Likely, the program finished and sent the output to the console buffer, which is taking its sweet time actually displaying it. What you're seeing is output lag.

Answer (score 2):

To become confident in what you see is what really happens, write for test sake:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(5000);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
Console.WriteLine("Run took {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
        (int)duration.TotalHours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);
```

Also, it's better to use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class for your purposes

Comment: On longer runs it seems less inaccurate. I was even wondering if the console is lagging a few seconds behind the actual ed of the program... it writes a lot of lines to the console. I'll maybe compare `StopWatch` and see if the same results are seen.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Stopwatch?

```
Stopwatch ss = new Stopwatch();
ss.Start();
// Some quantity of work..... 
ss.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", ss.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime isn't very accurate for this kind of measurement. You should use the stopwatch class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: Not accurate to the nearest _second_? I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: @John, I do agree. Perhaps you can try it turning off the console output in the main methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
Thread.Sleep(5000);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
Console.WriteLine(duration.Seconds);
```

Prints "5". Are you sure your test case is what it is?

Comment: Your test case isn't the same as mine. Write a few thousand lines to the console and time it by hand Vs what the timer tells you and let me know what you see?

Comment: @John yes, the console lags.

Comment: Thanks. That seems fairly conclusive then.